# How to Pre filled form data in the registration form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, registration

How to auto filled data, when I enter URL like **xxx.com/customer/account/create?firstname=test** it shows value test in firstname field as per the screenshot

[image]

Here is the path and code of first name.

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.php

```
<div class="field field-name-firstname required">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?= ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') ? ' data-validate="{required:true}"' : '' ?>>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the data for form value populating were got from
**`$block->getFormData()`**

For example

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name::class)->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
```

Look into
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Form/Register.php#L132
where you could populate data for your account register form.

You could plugin after into this **`Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register:getFormData()`**

and modify the result, here your is parameter firstname you could get from **`Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`**

On plugin of Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register

```
$subject->getRequest()->getParam('firstname');
```